# Object property being set by another class method

Tags: c#, properties, location, geocoding

I am trying to set my object property "Location" from a another class called Geocoding. Geocoder is a package I installed in order to convert an address to a lat lon location. It has this method properties and constructor.

```
   public class Geocoding
    {
        private readonly IGeocoder _geocoder;

        public Geocoding(IGeocoder geocoder)
        {
            _geocoder = geocoder;

        }

        private IList<Address> _Items;

        public IList<Address> Items
        {
            get { return _Items; }
            set
            {
                _Items = value;

            }
        }

        public async Task<Location> Geocode(string address)
        {

            try
            {
                _Items = await _geocoder.GetAddressesAsync(address).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Items = null;
            }

            return (new Location(_Items[0].Latitude, _Items[1].Longitude));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set my object like so: but my property and maybe the object stays null not sure why...:

```
public async Task AddBottles(Object object)
    {
        object.Location = await geocoder.Geocode(object.Address);
    }
```

Address is another property from my object that has been set already.

**UPDATE**

updated code with surroundings. Its simply in a method by itself. object represents a model class.

**UPDATE 2**

Also this might be of use to call my method Gecode I have a private variable:

```
private Geocoding geocoder;
```

And its highlighted green saying -> `is never assigned to will always have a value of null`

Comment: From what I see this part of code is correct. The problem might be where you are using this method. Please post the code around `object.Location = await geocoder.Geocode(object.Address);`

Comment: Apparently, your code is not correct in terms of exception handling. In case exception is thrown and caught, you'l first set _Items to null and two lines below will try to access the 0-th element of _Items, causing another exception.

Comment: Also check that `_geocoder.GetAddressesAsync` doesn't throw error and fall into catch. Good idea is to remove try-catch for debugging

Comment: And another question about _Items[0].Latitude, _Items[1].Longitude - you're reading lat and lon from two different items - is that correct? Maybe you need _Items[0].Latitude, _Items[0].Longitude?

Comment: I literally don't know how to use this plugin into my example... https://github.com/SeeD-Seifer/Mvx.Geocoder